# Haven't or didn't?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

How it is correct to say, 'I haven't received your email' or 'I didn't received your email'?

Answer (score 2):

Present Perfect and Past Simple are two concurent tenses. They often are interchangeable, especially in American English. So you can say either:

> I haven't received your email.

or

> I didn't *receive* your email.

Note that "I didn't *received* your email" is not correct because you cannot use -ed form of the main verb since you already have the verb "didn't".

Comment: They're both good in BrE too

Comment: I have one more question, if you will be willing to help me :)
When I have to talk about 'sign in'...it's correct to use the expression 'clock ed in'
For example: 'I saw that nobody was clock in, so I stayed online a little bit more'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly about it. I think it may be kind of a slang expression.

Comment: @Dede: It would have to be *I saw that nobody [else?] was **clocked** in*, but note that almost no-one would use ***clock in*** to mean ***sign in*** (or the online equivalent ***log in***) except in contexts where an employer requires you to record the time you arrive at or start (paid) work.